# como transformar el resultado en un objeto?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo esta funcion que ejecuta el codigo. Lo que necesitaria hacer es tranformar el resultado en un objeto. Tengo que crear un objeto y luego pushear el resultado?

```
pedirComida([{nombre: "Harry", dieta: "standard"}, {nombre: "Luna", dieta: 'vegan'}, {nombre: "Goyle", dieta: "standard"}])
// retorna {standard: 2, vegan: 1}
```

---

```
function pedirComida(array) {
  
   
  contador1 = 0;
  contador2 = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   if(array[i].dieta === 'standard'){
    contador1 ++;
   }
   else if(array[i].dieta === 'vegan'){
    contador2 ++
   }}
   
   return ('standard : ' + contador1 + ', vegan: ' + contador2);
  
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesariamente, con tan solo retornar un objeto en donde los valores sean `contador1` y `contador2` bastaría, ejemplo:

```js
function pedirComida(array) {
  contador1 = 0;
  contador2 = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].dieta === 'standard') {
      contador1++;
    } else if (array[i].dieta === 'vegan') {
      contador2++;
    }
  }

  return { standard: contador1, vegan: contador2 };
}

console.log(pedirComida([
  { nombre: 'Harry', dieta: 'standard' },
  { nombre: 'Luna', dieta: 'vegan' },
  { nombre: 'Goyle', dieta: 'standard' },
]))
```

Comment: ah perfecto! no lo podia resolver, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Aquí un forma usando métodos de array

```js
function pedirComida(array = []) {
  const standard = array.reduce((total, item) => total + (item.dieta === "standard" ? 1 : 0), 0);
  const vegan = array.reduce((total, item) => total + (item.dieta === "vegan" ? 1 : 0), 0);
  return { standard, vegan };
}

pedirComida([
  { nombre: "Harry", dieta: "standard" },
  { nombre: "Luna", dieta: "vegan" },
  { nombre: "Goyle", dieta: "standard" }
]);
```